# value from another controller using button click

Tags: angularjs

I've below requirement.

I've three controllers, ctrl 1, ctrl 2 and ctrl 3. I want to pass the value firstName to ctrl 1, lastName to ctrl2 and get the full name from ctrl3 using button click event.

I've tried my below code but I'm getting output as NaN.
Please help.

```
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


    myApp.factory('data', function () {

        var factory = {};
        var firstName = '';
        var secondName = '';
        factory.getName = function () {
            return firstName + ' ' + secondName;
        }
        return factory;
    });

    myApp.controller('FirstController', function ($scope, data) {
        $scope.firstName = data.firstName
    });

    myApp.controller('SecondController', function ($scope, data) {
        $scope.secondName = data.secondName;
    });
    myApp.controller('ThirdController', function ($scope, data) {
        $scope.getFullName = function () {
            $scope.fullName = data.getName();
        }
    });
</script>
```

```
    <h2>Controller 1</h2><br />
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.firstName">
        <br>FirstName is : {{data.firstName}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h2>Controller 2</h2><br />
    <div ng-controller="SecondController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="data.secondName">
        <br>LastName is : {{data.secondName}}
    </div>
    <h2>Controller 3</h2><br />
    <div ng-controller="ThirdController">
        <button ng-click="getFullName()">Get full Name</button>
        Full name is: {{fullName}}
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: use services for these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="BaseController">
    <p>Base Controller Value: {{model.getValue()}}</p>
    <button ng-click="model.updateValue('Value updated from Base')">Update In Base</button>
    <div ng-controller="DerivedController">
        <p>Derived Controller Value: {{model.getValue()}}</p>
        <button ng-click="model.updateValue('Value updated from Derived')">Update In Derived</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.factory('sharedModel', function () {
    // private stuff
    var model = {
        value: "initial Value"
    };
    // public API
    return {
        getValue:    function() { 
           return model.value; 
        },
        updateValue: function(value) {
           model.value = value;
        }
    };
});

function BaseController($scope, sharedModel) {
    $scope.model = sharedModel;
}

function DerivedController($scope, sharedModel) {
    $scope.model = sharedModel;
}
```

**[WorkingFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/gY3uZ/)**.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Issues in your code snippet:

- The service does not know about firstName and secondName properties.
- `data` is not a `$scope` object in first and second controller.
- No object allocation for the property in the service. "Save" button to bind to service.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


    myApp.service('data', function () {

        var service = {};
        service.firstName = '';
        service.secondName = '';
        service.getName = function () {
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.secondName;
        }
        return service;
    });

    myApp.controller('FirstController', function ($scope, data) {
    
        $scope.saveToService = function() {
            data.firstName = $scope.firstName;
        }
        
    });

    myApp.controller('SecondController', function ($scope, data) {
        $scope.saveToService = function() {
          data.secondName =$scope.secondName;
        }
        
    });
    myApp.controller('ThirdController', function ($scope, data) {
        $scope.getFullName = function () {
            $scope.fullName = data.getName();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <h2>Controller 1</h2><br />
    <div ng-controller="FirstController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
        <button ng-click="saveToService()">Save</button>
        <br>FirstName is : {{firstName}}
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h2>Controller 2</h2><br />
    <div ng-controller="SecondController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="secondName">
         <button ng-click="saveToService()">Save</button>
        <br>LastName is : {{secondName}}
    </div>
    <h2>Controller 3</h2><br />
    <div ng-controller="ThirdController">
        <button ng-click="getFullName()">Get full Name</button>
        Full name is: {{fullName}}
        </div>

</body>
```